# manuals for os development?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, manual

manuals for os development?

I wonder what manuals out there for os development.

I wonder how can I access first sector of HDD/USB Drive
where does it loaded into, location of frame buffer, and so on.

can someone please let me know where can I find such official manuals?

Comment: https://wiki.osdev.org/ isn't "official", but it's pretty good.  See also other links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to Intel / AMD official manuals.  (Which document the CPU itself, mostly not the devices or the legacy BIOS or EFI software functions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic tutorial on how to make an OS (assuming you mean operating system): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MJUGVFAXKg.

It's pretty good, but you need to learn the *assembly language* first (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language).

Hope I helped!

Comment: thank you very much. I wonder if you can recommend me some official manual also.

Comment: I don't think an "official manual" exists, because creating OS's isn't run by a single organization -_-

Answer (score 1):

"Operating System Design and Implementation" by Andrew S. Tanenbaum and Albert S. Woodhull.

It takes you through step-by-step, and if you follow the instructions you should end up with an OS at the end.

Comment: PS - be very careful - I managed to write a wrong boot sector (= first sector) to the wrong place many years ago... on a computer that wasn't mine... I managed to recover the data before the school found out :)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I am looking for an official document but it might be helpful too!

Comment: The spec dates back to before 1983 (MBRs came in in '83). You might find some of what you want at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector